# Is 'a five years later' gramatically correct?

Tags: articles

I'm a native Slovakian speaker, and currently, I am at an English competition. I was met with this sentence: "..., and *a five years later*, he became a professional musician." Is the *a* in there correct? I have never seen it being used like this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Chinese and also an English major. I think there should be no "a" before "five years later".

Comment: I am also thinking about that. It was weird, because I had to add a word (I added five), because after the word, there was "years later". But the "a" before the word did confuse me.

Comment: This is true. The 'a' is not supposed to be there.

Comment: What about 'a couple years later'?

Comment: Are you saying that you had to supply a word to fill the gap in _a - years later_ ? If so, _few_ would do. In British English, at least, it has to be _a couple of_.

Comment: Yes, I had to supply a word to fill the gap. My English teacher told me that couple would do (we are being reached British English), but I didn't think about few. Thanks! I think I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question as well as other details you provided in comments on the question, the "a" should not be there in

> "... and five years later, he became a professional musician."

If, however, you were asked to complete the following sentence:

> "... and a ____ years later, he became a professional musician."

then I would say that the missing word would be "few".

If you were asked for just one word then you would not be able to use "couple" since you would need "of" as well. That is,

> "... and a couple of years later, he became a professional musician."

Comment: I hear "a couple years later" all the time in English, but it may be an informal usage.

Comment: 'A couple' is becoming acceptable as a compound quantifier/numeral substitute (it depends on whether it's meant precisely), modelling on 'a few' and 'a dozen'. Covered at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/why-is-a-couple-of-things-often-shortened-to-a-couple-things).

Answer (score 1):

In particular, '*a five years*' doesn't make sense for a *logical* reason: **one is not five** - since the 'a' article is technically '**one**' (one of a class, by definition). To prevent both 'a' and 'five' referring to 'years' you can e. g. introduce another noun which would transform those 'five' into a single group: **a period of five years**. As for your sentence, you could use a *single* word (*no* preposition) to fill the gap:

> *a **dozen** years later*

.